# Notify Icon duplicates itself, when any event occurs

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have a notify icon in my Winforms form and it seems that when any kind of event happens the tray icon is duplicated.
I have debugged one of the issues, being that it is duplicated when the dialog box is closed after using it.

It happens in debug and when released.

The other issue it with a timer that runs method.

I cannot see why this happens. My timer ran 60 times last night and each time it has four methods to run and there were hundreds of icons in the tray.

My code is as follows:

```
         public Form1()
          {
                    InitializeComponent();

                    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Mappi CSV Manager is running.";
                    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Mappi CSV Manager";
                    notifyIcon1.Text = "Mappi CSV Manager";
          }

           private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
                    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                    {
                        ShowIcon = false;
                        ShowInTaskbar = false;
                        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
                    }
                }

                private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
                {
                    ShowInTaskbar = true;
                    notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
                    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

                }

                  protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
                {
                    base.OnClosed(e);
                    // Call Dispose to remove the icon out of notification area of Taskbar. 
                    notifyIcon1.Dispose();

                }

     protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
            {
                if (CloseCancel() == false)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                };
            }

     //When closing the form
        public static bool CloseCancel()
        {
            const string message = "If you close the program, no files will be generated!";
            const string caption = "Stop!";
            var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                                         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                         MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

  //Set new value for timer
        private void UdTimerValue_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(udTimerValue.Value) * 60000;
        }

        //Start generating CSV's
        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                if (AutoGenerateEnabled)
                {
                    richLogWindow.AppendText("CSV Created at: " + DateTime.Now + "\r\n");
                    var startdate = "";

                    if(DateTime.Now.Hour == 1)
                    {
                        richLogWindow.Clear();
                        startdate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        CSVGenerator.GenerateCSV(startdate, this);
                    }
                    else
                    {                        
                        startdate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        CSVGenerator.GenerateCSV(startdate, this);                        
                    }                    
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Why is this code producing another tray icon every time a button is clicked or an event happens.

TIA

Comment: Don't we need to see the timer code?

Comment: find all references to notifyIcon1 and post all related codes

Comment: In terms of the form that is all of the references, they appear nowhere else. The only other place they appear is in the resx.

Comment: `The other issue it with a timer that runs method.`  You mentioned the timer, but we don't see the code for it.

Comment: I have updated the code to show the Timer_Tick event;

Comment: `ShowInTaskbar = true;` is an expensive property.  By changing it, you are making windows destroy the window and rebuild it again.  It might be the cause of your problems.

Comment: I know what it is now. I pass the form to the various operations, so I can log messages in a richTextBox in the form. This is obviously duplicating the form, this can be seen in the timer_tick event where I pass `this` to a method or property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. I have put `RichTextBoxAppend.AddNewText("test me", new Form1());` the new form was created each time a process was run. I am an idiot!